Animated movie about a snake, spaceship and end of world
When I was a child there was a movie I loved, but I cannot for the life of me remember it.
Here's all I remember about it:

It was animated
It involved a woman who was turned (could turn) into a snake
There was a flying craft (poss. spaceship) shaped like a snake
The woman / snake and a man (poss. henchman) were trying to take over / destroy the world
They were stealing landmarks (Big Ben, Eiffel Tower etc) and miniaturising them


You're looking for Freddie as F.R.O.7. from 1992.

The story about a man-sized frog named Prince Frederic who is turned into a frog by his wicked aunt Messina and hired by British Intelligence to solve the mysterious disappearances of some of Britain's greatest monuments.

Messina can turn into a cobra, among other things. Here's the trailer:



